# Expand activity window from an imageView in Android

Tags: android, animation, expand

I would like to know how to expand the window of a new activity from a shared element, like in this animation :

http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/videos/animations-meaningfultransitions-hierarchical_transitions_topLevel_large_xhdpi.webm

If it is not possible, how can I animate the status bar ?
And how can I expand a cropped image to its real size without distorsion (height) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared element transition for achieving transition animation.
Below links may help you :

1. http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2015/01/activity-fragment-shared-element-transitions-in-depth-part3a.html
2. http://www.androidauthority.com/using-shared-element-transitions-activities-fragments-631996/